# How can i use DI in CustomRepository(nestjs)

Tags: nestjs

I want use [ConfigService](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) on [CustomerRepository](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database).

So, i try like this

```
export class CrawlerRepository extends Repository<Crawler> {
  constructor(
    private readonly config: ConfigService,
  ) { super(); }
}
```

But it does not works.(i think because custom repository not be instantiated by nestjs)

How can i access ConfigService in CustomRepository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to use DI in a repository, the repository itself would have to be an injectable.

```
@Injectable()
export class CrawlerRepository extends Repository<Crawler> {
  constructor(private readonly config: ConfigService) {
    super();
  }
}
```

Then the `CrawlerRepository` Will need to be added to a module as a provider

```
@Module({
  providers: [CrawlerRepository],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The Module will also need to import the ConfigService before your CrawlerRepository is instanced.